# Site default URL in Liferay with Velocity

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I'm using Liferay 6.2 and I would like to get the **default site URL** using **Velocity**.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this to work? If so post the details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try if `$themeDisplay.getURLHome()` cuts it.</strike>

UPDATE: `$site_default_url`

See example in Liferay's unstyle theme: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/a1329911eab1430b2fba1d2dbf09843aab6c2bb6/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/portal_normal.vm#L29

Comment: I tried it but it shows the URL of the portal's home page , not the community ( Site )

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()`